# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'setSubmitting' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, undefined, formik

Getting the following error : Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'setSubmitting' of undefined

```
  async function handleSubmit(values, formikProps) {
        const data = { ...values };
        const { setSubmitting } = formikProps;
        await submitBookStaff(data);
        setSubmitting(false);
    }
```

Expecting to have a success action on my handleSubmit to change the status ID.

Comment: How is `formikProps` argument being passed to this function? The error is that argument is undefined.

Comment: Is the form/component wrapped with `withFormik`?